# How to find the singular solution of $y'=\frac{2x+y}{y-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'$ and $y$ occur linearly in the ODE
$$y'=\frac{2x+y}{y-x}.$$
yet it is a first order non-linear ODE. I can find a family  solutions of this homogeneous ODE by using $y=vx \implies \frac{dy}{dx}= v+x \frac{dv}{dx}$. I want to know if there is(are) singular solution(s) of this equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the singular solution of this equation by puttin $y=vx$, but treat $v$ as constant for a change. then
$$v=\frac{2+v}{v-1} \implies v=1\pm \sqrt{3} ~~real~~.$$ so the singular solutions are
$y=(1+\sqrt{3})x, ~ y=(1-\sqrt{3}) x.$ These are essential solutions free from any constant. These solutions occur if one gets real value(s) of $v$ as in this examples. If so, the origin is either a node (stable /unstable) or a saddle point. These singular(essential) solutions are  apart from the usual solution which will depend on a given initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

$$ y'=\frac{x(2+\frac{y}{x})}{x(\frac{y}{x}-1)} $$ 
then you can make a replacement $$  t=\frac{y}{x} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx}x+t \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{dx}x+t=\frac{2+t}{t-1}     $$
It remains only to divide the variables and take the integral :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$y'=\frac{2+\frac{y}{x}}{-1+\frac{y}{x}}$$ and substitute $$u=\frac{y}{x}$$